# Send Image along text to server in android

Tags: android, image

```
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
DataOutputStream dos = null;
String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary = "*****";
int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
byte[] buffer;
int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
    Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File Does not exist");
    return 0;
}
try { // open a URL connection to the Servlet
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
    URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
    conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
    conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
    conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

    // text to send

    conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

    String stringFieldName = "user_id";

    conn.setRequestProperty("user_id", "999");

    conn.setRequestProperty("sb_name", "testinggg");

    Log.e("fileName", "fileName     ======="+fileName);
    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    Log.e("uploadFile_uploadFile", "twoHyphens ="+twoHyphens +", boundary ="+boundary+", lineEnd ="+lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

    Random r = new Random();
    int rnd_filename = r.nextInt(999) + 1;
    String strFileName="";
    strFileName =rnd_filename +".png";

    Log.e("strFileName", "strFileName     ======="+strFileName);
    // dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ strFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + stringFieldName + "\""+ lineEnd);

    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);               

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of  maximum size

    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // read file and write it into form...
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 

    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // Responses from the server (code and message)
    serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

    Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
    if(serverResponseCode == 200){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tv.setText("File Upload Completed.");
                Toast.makeText(UploadImageDemo.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }   

    //close the streams //
    fileInputStream.close();
    dos.flush();
    dos.close();

} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
    System.out.println("catch MalformedURLException ");
    System.out.println("catch MalformedURLException ex ="+ex);
    dialog.dismiss();
    ex.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(UploadImageDemo.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("catch Exception ");
    System.out.println("catch Exception ex ="+e);
    dialog.dismiss();
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(UploadImageDemo.this, "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
}

try {
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("RESULT Message: " + line);
    }
    rd.close();
} catch (IOException ioex) {
    Log.e("Huzza", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
}

dialog.dismiss();
System.out.println("uploadFile END");
return serverResponseCode;
}
```

I want to upload image as well as text to the server.I  am able to send the image to server but unable to send the text on the server.

Answer (score 0):

this way i did it and working

```
 //text with the image
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=text" + lineEnd); // GET text in PHP side
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(UserPost); // mobile_no is String variable
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                   //Username with image
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=usr" + lineEnd); // GET usr in PHP side
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(name); 
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```